# issue with chrome when using jquery ui draggable for horizontal scrolling website

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

My site (http://www.enginelabs.ca) is built using a database and php to bring in projects dynamically. I used jquery draggable to scroll through the projects and a javascript function that wraps the projects into a table format so it's easier to display horizontally.

The issue I'm having is the projects sometimes jump down and get cut off. It happens on safari and chrome but not on firefox. And when I go to index.php page it seems to fix itself.
I can give more details on how things are coded if need be.

[Here is a JS Fiddle link showing the code in action](http://jsfiddle.net/kREqh/3/embedded/result/).

Thanks dudes!

Comment: It's very hard to provide assistance without at least some sample code.  Can you [set up a minimal JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which demonstrates the problem and add a link in your question?

Comment: Ive never used this before so I hope that's good enough? It can't load much because it doesn't have images and the jquery isn't loading.

Comment: I added a <base> tag and made the script `src` values absolute to make the images and Javascript all work.  Generally, it's best to update your question with information like this.  I'll edit your post to add the link.

Comment: BTW, if you can provide a screenshot showing the bad behavior on Safari/Chrome, that may also help.  I'm afraid this one is likely beyond my present skills to resolve, but other folks on SO may be up to the challenge.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't know about jsfiddle before that's the only reason I didn't give you that upfront.
You can find the images here:
http://enginelabs.ca/blog.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason (I stumbled on this by accident after 20 seconds)

```
 vertical-align: baseline
```

on your table cells seems to be causing the problem. Maybe it's because you're setting the height with jQuery or something, and there's some bug or quirk in Webkit or... anyways.

Explicitly setting vertical-align to something other than baseline may fix it, try it.

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: alright that worked! Thanks alot, srry for the late reply just been busy.